# How to reference a shared object file in multiple modules in Android NDK?

Tags: android, logging, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I have a logger module in my project, this has been built as an shared object; so that it can be referenced from different modules in the same project. But facing issues during linking. My folder structure is like

```
jni
|- Logger (Folder Logger)
|- Module a(Folder a)
|- Module b(Folder b)
|- Module c(Folder c)
```

Logger has Android.mk file and creating the shared object of the logger. This logger module is being referenced from modules a, b & c. During compilation it is fine, but during linking getting `undefined reference to` error in all the modules for logger functions. I am referencing them in `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := logger` in other modules. If I try to include the `Logger/Android.mk` file in the modules then getting error `module was already defined`. I tried including like `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llogger` as well. But no luck :(.

Please let me know if anyone has resolved this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do include of the `Logger/Android.mk` file in multiple modules. Include the same in the Parent `Android.mk file (jni/Android.mk)` and in the rest of the modules define in `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := logger`.

My Mistake. I did an `include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../Logger/Android.mk` in all the other modules as well.